# Getting data from database and then outputing it to the DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am at the point where I feel that I am not doing it right. It works and does the job, but I am sure that there are more efficient and smarter ways of doing it.

I would like to see if there is a way of making it more efficient, clear, and easier to use.

This is my query getter:

```
    public DataTable querySQL_DT_Return(String query)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
        DataTable RETURNME = null;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cnStr);

        try
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to the database!");
            }

            OleDbDataAdapter Data1 = null;

            try
            {
                Data1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't open the connection to the DB, please try again!");
                return RETURNME;
            }

            DataSet a = new DataSet();
            Data1.Fill(a);

            DataTable dt = a.Tables[0];
            //Adding data to the columns
            RETURNME = dt;
        }

        catch
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Having issues retrieving data from Database, please try again!");
            // return RETURNME;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {

            conn.Close();
        }
        return RETURNME;
    }
```

When I receive the DataTable, I just loop through it getting records.

Comment: ORM/data binding can help, but when you need hand-coded customization(such as not displaying everything, or displaying things differently), you might want to have a method return an `IList<CustomObject>` where you define the `CustomObject` class. I have helper methods `RunQueryExpectOneTable` and `RunProcExpectOneTable` which both return a `DataTable`. Then, you can call these and iterate over the rows ...

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are stuck with the old/wrong technology (all the cool kids use ORMs these days), you can still dance around that and simplify the act of interfacing with it with clean code of your own. I like having a direct link to the database because I can do whatever the hell I want with it. If the author of an ORM library and I had different goals and priorities, then this library will actually hinder my productivity. Disclaimer: I have little experience with ORMs.

Anyhow, try using lots of smaller functions.
Try passing everything a method needs in - that way you can move this code into a separate class.
Use exception handling to signal that something went wrong. Do not use the MessageBox / return null combination. You might be running this code as a windows service where showing Message Boxes is not allowed. It also does not feel right. The error handling / display effort needs to be well thought out, not copy /pasted into every method.
Features are assets; code is liability, hence less code is more.
Try using descriptive variable/method/etc. names.

```
public DataTable RunQueryExpectOneTable(
    string queryText,
    string[] expectedColumnNames = null)
{
    return RunQueryExpectOneTable(
    connectionString: this.ConnectionString,
    queryText: queryText,
    expectedColumnNames: expectedColumnNames);
}

public static DataTable RunQueryExpectOneTable(
    string connectionString,
    string queryText,
    string[] expectedColumnNames = null)
{
    // Even the body of this using method is too long, it can be further split up into methods.
    using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Opens it and makes sure that it is open.
        this.OpenAndCheckConnection();
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        // if more than one table, then throw an exception.
        if (expectedColumnNames != null)
        {
            // Also check the number and the names of the columns
        }

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using entity framework and direct data binding.  Unless you are doing something fancy, you shouldn't have to manually loop through records to create UI elements.

Comment: Additionally, the simplest solution is just to directly data bind to the DataSet or DataTable objects.  Of course, I would generally agree that mapping the data to more specific data structures is better, but it is not required.  How complicated to make it depends on what the code will ultimately be used for.